# Step into Stored Proc gives "Canceled by User" in VS 2010 but works in VS 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2010

I'm running a local instance of SQL 2008 standard on my workstation.
Also have VS 2008 and VS 2010 installed on it.
I've (for this test) disabled the Kaspersky AV and ensure windows firewall is off.

When I debug a stored proc on my local SQL instance by right clicking and selecting "Step Into Stored Procedure" in VS 2008 it works.  I get the dialog for the parameters and can step into the SP line by line.

When I try the same thing with VS 2010 against my local SQL instance, I never get the parameter dialog, but rather get "Canceled by user" in the debug output.

Can anyone point me to a VS 2010 resolution for this?

Thanks,
Ken